# Build multidimensional array from string naming key values in php

Tags: php, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, key-value

So I have this problem, I am extracting a string from excel that has this structure:

> 89.356 87.54, 45.34 98.254, 45.2413 45.2146, 98.23 35.647

And I want to build an array with the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['first'] => 89.356 
            ['second'] => 87.54
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['first'] => 45.34 
            ['second'] => 98.254
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['first'] => 45.2413
            ['second'] => 45.2146
        )
)
```

I am extracting these values from an excel and creating the array like this:

```
$polygons = $sheet->getCell("B".$row)->getValue();
        $ret = array_map (
            function ($) {return explode (' ', $);},
            explode (',', $polygons)
        );
```

But I do not know how to assign the key values 'first' and 'second' to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, just to point out that your code will produce an error because you can't create a variable without a name ex. in your code you only have **$** as variable.

Here's how you do it.

```
$ret = array_map( function( $pol ) {
    $a = array_map( 'floatval', explode( ' ', $pol, 2 ) ); // 1

    return array_combine( ['first', 'second'], $a ); // 2
}, explode( ',', $polygons ) );
```

1. Convert from string to float.
2. Assign the first array (['first', 'second']) as key to the second array

Output: var_dump( $ret );

```
array(3) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        ["first"] => float(89.356),
        ["second"] => float(89.356),
    },
    [1] => array(2) {
        ["first"] => float(45.34),
        ["second"] => float(98.254),
    },
    [2] => array(2) {
        ["first"] => float(45.2413),
        ["second"] => float(45.2146,
    },
}
```

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for your help, I am completely new with php, in fact this is my first day giving it a try, so this was really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @mickmackusa. I was just assuming that it would only contain 2 floating numbers.

Comment: @IsraelChavez Happy to help. :)

Comment: @mickmackusa Just accepted the answer, sorry! I did not knew I had to do that.